# Surface Tablet can't find wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-rt

I had my Surface tablet with Windows 8 RT working until I changed my router to another one to support optical fiber.

All my other devices (cell phone, laptop with Windows 7, MacBook) work well with this new router except my Surface tablet.

I have tried everything... from manually adding a new wireless network to formatting the tablet.

Does anyone know if there is any reason for this behavior?

Comment: Do you have any more info? What router did you switch to? Did you get any errors? Did you have to do anything special on the other devices to get them to switch?

Comment: Did you keep the same SSID?  Perhaps the Windows 8 RT device is confused if the SSID stayed the same.  Is there an option in Windows 8 RT to forget a network?  Have you tried that?  i.e. tell Windows 8 RT to forget about your old connection and learn it all over.

Comment: Also, make sure your router isn't using [channels 12-14](http://superuser.com/questions/329152/whats-the-significance-if-any-of-wifi-channels-12-14). Your router may have also switched to a channel with more interference that for whatever reason the surface cant cope with. Use a tool like inSSIDer to see what channel your router is selecting and if it overlaps with neighbors strong channels.

Comment: Doug, channel is setted to 13 + 9 (whatever it means)... I´ll try to get the user and password from Movistar and change that config. Thanks