# Can't find router after channel-change

Tags: wireless-networking

I tried optimizing the signal strength of my router by changing its channel.
Now, my wifi-antenna can't find the router (and its repeater as well).

I went right next to the router to check if I could get signal that way, but no.

I have Windows 8.1 and I changed the routers channel to 13.
I deleted the routers and repeaters profile with `#netsh` but still no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you are Channel 13 is not legal to use (See [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/329152/820) and the [list of channels on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#Interference_Concerns)).  Its likely your Wi-Fi adapter does not support tuning to Channel 13. I would suggest connecting to your router with an Ethernet cable to change the configuration.  If you can do that you'll probably have to reset the router to defaults.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the best channel for your WIFI download the app called [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/support/downloads/).

This app should show you all the available AP nearby and also which channels they are using.